# How to check if jQM popup fits user's viewport?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, user-experience

So I've managed to [add scrollbars to large jQM popups with `css('overflow-y', 'scroll')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723788/jquery-mobile-popup-content-height-exceeds-window-height). But how to do this **only** when the popup is larger than the user's viewport?

I'm trying with the [jquery-visible](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible) plugin but I can't get it to respond:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmRnq/124/

```
$('#test-button').on('click', function(e) {     
  $('#confirmDialog').popup('open');

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791374/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-in-viewport  

  if(!$('#confirmDialog').visible(true)) {
    alert('Popup not fully visible - add overflow scrolling');
    $('#confirmDialog').css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); 
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
overflow-y: auto
```

This makes the scrollbar only visible when it is needed.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mmRnq/125/)**

**UPDATE:**

You can also just make the content of the popup scrollable so the titlebar remains in view:

```
#confirmDialog .ui-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

$('#confirmDialog').on({
  popupbeforeposition: function() {
      var maxHeight = $(window).height() - 120;
      $('#confirmDialog .ui-content').height(maxHeight);
  }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mmRnq/126/)**

Comment: @MarkBoulder, you are welcome, if you want just the content scrollable instead of the entire popup, see this update: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mmRnq/126/

Answer (score 0):

I had a popup too large, although it was because of a searchable list.  As I wanted to keep the search field at the top whilst scrolling the list only, I had to do this:

```
$("#confirmDialog").on({
    popupbeforeposition: function (e, ui) {
        var maxHeight = $(window).height() - 100 + "px";
        $("#confirmDialog .ui-content").css("max-height", maxHeight);
    },
    popupafteropen: function (e, ui) {
        var maxHeight = $(window).height() - 150 + "px";
        $("#confirmDialog .ui-content ul").css("max-height", maxHeight).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    }
});
```

Remember do not perform arithmetic on `maxHeight` once assigned as it's a string, so this doesn't work:

```
$("#confirmDialog .ui-content").css("max-height", maxHeight - 50);
```